# Calling FileOpenPicker in OnNavigatedTo works only on Win 10 on PC but not on Win 10 Mobile

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In a UWP App, I want to prompt the user to pick a file when navigated to a page.

I am overriding the method `OnNavigatedTo` in the page and calling the picker from it. It works on PC unproblematic. But when I run it on a mobile device with Windows 10 Mobile (Lumia 640), it does not work!

Just to test, if I call `CameraCaptureUI` instead of the `FileOpenPicker`, it works unproblematic on both PC and Mobile!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Calling FileOpenPicker in OnNavigatedTo works only on Win 10 on PC but not on Win 10 Mobile

The problem is that the mobile is low performance device. Calling the picker immediately after the navigate method will cause the device to become unresponsive. So you could add the task delay before calling piker like the following

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    await Task.Delay(100);

    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```